# Printing ASCII Diamond Figure in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, function, ascii

I trying to print something like this:

```
+--------+
|   /\   |
|  /--\  |
| /====\ |
|<------>|
| \====/ |
|  \--/  |
|   \/   |
+--------+
```

So far I have sucessfully printed the first part of the figure but having a hard time with the second part.

This is how I am printing the first part of the figure:

```
for (int fill = 0; fill <= ((2 * row - 1)); fill++) {

    if ((row % 2) == 0) {
     System.out.print("=");
    } else {
     System.out.print("-");
    }
   }
```

The second part I have is

```
for (int fill = 0; fill <= (n - 2 * (row - 1)); fill++) { //This is where I need help
    if ((row % 2) == 0) {
     System.out.print("=");
    } else {
     System.out.print("-");
    }
   }
```

My outcome looks like this:

```
+--------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|   /\   |                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|  /--\  |                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
| /====\ |                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|<------>|                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
| \=====/ |                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
|  \---/  |                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
|   \=/   |                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
+--------+
```

For the full code please check: http://pastebin.com/YyCJ6Cq3

Comment: fill <= ((n - 2 * (row - 1))-1)

Comment: Thank you very much for including both a relevant code snippet in your question and also sharing a complete runnable example. Welcome to the community!

Comment: +1 for rare new user who provides everything we need. It is a valid question even if it is homework (we see your effort), Welcome thuzle :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see you're printing one too many columns inside the diamond. So the fix should be simple - print one less column each time, which you do by reducing the number of times the your loop runs by one. Generally speaking you could just add a `- 1` to the end of the conditional like @samgak suggests, but this won't actually work here. Let's try to understand *why* you're running into this issue.

Your first loop doesn't depend on `n`; it only uses the current row index to determine how many characters to print.

In the second loop you correctly need to also include `n` in order to start large and decrease the value of `fill`, but you're misusing it. `n` and `row` are of the same magnitude (since `row` is defined in terms of `n`) yet you only multiply `row` by `2`. Instead you should do the `n-row` operation first, *then* scale the result by `2` in order to print 2x characters in each row. You'll have to play with it a little further since `2*(n-row)` isn't quite right, but hopefully that's enough to help you figure out your issue.

Comment: for(int fill=0; fill<=2*(n-row)-5;fill++) did the trick! thanks

Comment: @thuzle think about *why* `-5` did the trick. Consider restructuring it to `2*(n-row-2)-1`, which is equivalent but more clearly shows that `n-row` is two more than the range you need, and then the range needs to be shifted down one more.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a school project, thus I will only give hints. The conditional statement looks like it has one too many fill.

```
fill <= (n - 2 * (row - 1));
```

Comment: @dimo414 This answer doesn't show solution, but points to code fragment with is causing problem (with hint what problem is). Seeing that this question looks like homework (I don't have problem with it since it has all necessary parts to be good question) I would say it is enough for an answer (perfect for comment, but still enough for an answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try: fill <= (n - (2 * (row -1) +1);
Or: fill < (n - 2 * (row -1));

Comment: You should [edit your original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38214793/edit) instead of answering twice.